# How to change controllers for queued builds

Tags: tfs, build

It's not really "on fire", it's just desperately beeping until it gets unplugged and given the once over with a can of air.

This leaves me with a number of queued builds and a question: **How can I change the build controller of this builds so that they run on another build machine?**

I know how to queue new builds, and this isn't too bad as they don't really require any configuration. However, it seems a touch unnecessary. Additionally, it would be nice if I could re-direct all of the queued builds for the aforementioned, currently out of commission, build machine at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory you could create another controller and when you are doing the install, you could tell it to replace the existing controller. this however is only a theory and would cause you issues when you reintroduced your overheated machine ( as the controller would no longer be tied to TFS)

if this is a regular thing, perhaps move the controller to a different machine and just leave the agents on the suspect machine. you could then easily add additional agents to the stable controller should the machine overheat again